# How to Insert values into two tables?

Tags: c#, winforms, insert

I have a medicalcentre and windowsadmin table which have relationship with each other using mcID. I have 4 inputs in the form. two of the inputs which is the mcType and mcCentre values that are entered should insert to medicalcentre table and two of the other two inputs which is winUsername and winPassword values that are entered should go to the windowsadmin table.

That means what I want is, I type in vales for mcType, mcCentre, winUsername and winPassword. When click register, the mcCentre and mcType will be inserted into medicalcentre table and auto increment one mcID, that mcID will be inserted into window admin table along with the winUsername and winPassword that are entered. How to do it? For my codes below. I only know how to insert mcType and mcCentre which is in the medicalcentre table only.

**My Register MedicalCentre and WindowsAdmin account form**

Radio button names - Hospital : rbHopistal

Radio button names - Clinic : rbClinic

textbox name - mcCentre : txtmcCentre

textbox name - winUsername : txtwinUsername

textbox name - winPassword : txtwinPassword

[image: My Register MedicalCentre and WindowsAdmin account form]

**MEDICAL CENTRE AND WINDOWSADMIN table**
[image: MEDICAL CENTRE AND WINDOWSADMIN table]

Error Trying to follow @Sergey Berezovskiy code. Must declare the scalar variable "@mcID".

[image: Must declare the scalar variable "@mcID]

**My tables Relationship**
  [image: My tables Relationship]

```
    private int AddMedicalCentreRecord()
            {
                int result = 0;

                string strConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SACPConnection"].ConnectionString;

                SqlConnection myConnect = new SqlConnection(strConnectionString);

                String strCommandText = "INSERT MEDICALCENTRE(mcType, mcCentre) "
                    + " VALUES (@NewmcType,@NewmcCentre)";

                SqlCommand updateCmd = new SqlCommand(strCommandText, myConnect);

                if (rbHopistal.Checked)
                    updateCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NewmcType", "Hospital");
                else
                    updateCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NewmcType", "Clinic");
                updateCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NewmcCentre", txtmcCentre.Text);

                myConnect.Open();

                result = updateCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                // STEP 5: Close
                myConnect.Close();
                return result;
            }
```

Error Trying to follow @Sergey Berezovskiy code. Must declare the scalar variable "@mcID".

```
private int AddMedicalCentreRecord()
    {
        int result = 0;

        string strConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SACPConnection"].ConnectionString;

        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(strConnectionString))
        {
            conn.Open();
            using (SqlTransaction transaction = conn.BeginTransaction())
            {

                string insertCentreQuery =
                    @"INSERT MEDICALCENTRE (mcType, mcCentre) 
          VALUES (@NewmcType, @NewmcCentre)
          SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()";

                SqlCommand insertCentreCmd =
                    new SqlCommand(insertCentreQuery, conn, transaction);

                if (rbHopistal.Checked)
                    insertCentreCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NewmcType", "Hospital");
                else
                    insertCentreCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NewmcType", "Clinic");
                insertCentreCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NewmcCentre", txtmcCentre.Text);

                int mcID = Convert.ToInt32(insertCentreCmd.ExecuteScalar());  

                string insertUserQuery =
                    @"INSERT WINDOWSADMIN (winUsername, winPassword, mcID)
          VALUES (@userName, @password, @mcID)";
                SqlCommand insertUserCmd =

                    new SqlCommand(insertUserQuery, conn, transaction);

                insertUserCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@userName", txtwinUsername.Text);
                insertUserCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", txtwinPassword.Text);

                insertUserCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                transaction.Commit();

                //conn.Open();

                //result = insertUserCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                conn.Close();
                return result;
            }
        }         


    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [transaction](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqltransaction%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) - begin transaction, then insert data into medicalcentre table and obtain mcID. After that insert data to windowsadmin table and commit transaction:

```
using(SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(strConnectionString))
{
    conn.Open();
    using(SqlTransaction transaction = conn.BeginTransaction())
    {
        // execute first command
        string insertCentreQuery = 
            @"INSERT MEDICALCENTRE (mcType, mcCentre) 
              VALUES (@NewmcType, @NewmcCentre)
              SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()";

        SqlCommand insertCentreCmd = 
            new SqlCommand(insertCentreQuery, conn, transaction);
        // ...provide command parameters
        int mcID = Convert.ToInt32(insertCentreCmd.ExecuteScalar());         

        // execute second command
        string insertUserQuery =
            @"INSERT WINDOWSADMIN (winUsername, winPassword, mcID)
              VALUES (@userName, @password, @mcID)";
        SqlCommand insertUserCmd = 
            new SqlCommand(insertUserQuery, conn, transaction);
        // ...provide command parameters
        insertUserCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        transaction.Commit();
    }   
}
```

Comment: I add in error codes, add in error images. What;s wrong and did i write correctly? @Sergey Berezovskiy

Comment: @Jordjmax you should provide command parameters before you execute command

Comment: This is a Command Parameters insertUserCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NewmcType", "Clinic"); right? But at the end i put  result = insertUserCmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); This is the execute command right? Isn't that correct? @Sergey Berezovskiy

Comment: @Jordjmax you have two commands here. You should create first command. Then provide its parameters. Then execute it. Same for second command. Currently you create first command and execute it without providing parameters (you add them later, after trying to execute command)

Comment: I see I think I get it, will try Thanks @Sergey Berezovskiy

Comment: Specified cast is not valid after entering all values and clicking register button. I got this error. Updated above codes and  image. @Sergey Berezovskiy

Comment: @Jordjmax what type of `mcID` column? Is it primary key column?

Comment: Yes, mcID is a primary key for Medicalcentre table. I added the image for relationship tables above @Sergey Berezovskiy

Comment: @Jordjmax OK, sorry - scope identity is decimal, so simple cast will not work. You should use `Convert.ToInt32` (I updated answer)

Comment: Must declare the scalar variable "@mcID see above. They want me to assign that variable @mcID to a textbox is it? but I dun wan to do that. What I want is - the mcCentre and mcType will be inserted into medicalcentre table and auto increment one mcID, that mcID will be inserted into window admin table along with the winUsername and winPassword that are entered.@Sergey Berezovskiy

Comment: @Jordjmax you need to provide id returned by first command execution to parameters of second command

Comment: Can provide me the code? I don't know how to write the return id lols. @Sergey Berezovskiy

Comment: @Jordjmax `insertUserCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@mcID" mcID);`